# Can someone please add an image as background to this program? (WXPython)

Tags: python, image, background, wxpython

Yeah, I know... i had asked a lot today (And so many thanks, Furas!). But look, I just need one thing and it'll be done. Could some one, please, for the love of God, add and image as background to this program with WXPython? It does not matter what image you put. Just put a random image, is the only thing i need. Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx, pygame, sys, random, os
from pygame.locals import *
from random import choice
from block import O, I, S, Z, L, J, T

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.InitUI()
    def InitUI(self):    
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer = wx.GridSizer(2, 2, 2, 2)

        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Tetris')
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label='Pong')
        btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label='Brik')

        sizer.AddMany([btn1, btn2, btn3])

        hbox.Add(sizer, 150, wx.ALL, 200)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)

        btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Mensaje1)
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Mensaje2)
        btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Mensaje3)

        self.SetSize((600, 500))
        self.SetTitle('Messages')
        self.Centre()
        frame.Show(True)

    def Mensaje1(self, event):
        [stuffs...]   
    def Mensaje2(self, event):
        [stuffs...]  
    def Mensaje3(self, event):
        [stuffs...]  
        print "Hell, World"
def main():

    ex = wx.App()
    Example(None)
    ex.MainLoop()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `panel` as a StaticBitmap's parent.

I removed some element to run this code.

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent=None, *args, **kwargs)        
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        try:
            self.image_filename = "roses.jpg"
            self.image = wx.Image(self.image_filename, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
            # parent: panel
            self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(panel, -1, self.image, (0, 0))
        except IOError:
            print "Image file %s not found" % self.image_filename
            raise SystemExit

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer()
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)

        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Tetris')
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label='Pong')
        btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label='Brik')

        sizer = wx.GridSizer(2, 2, 2, 2)
        sizer.AddMany([btn1, btn2, btn3])

        hbox.Add(sizer, 150, wx.ALL, 200)

        self.SetSize((600, 500))
        self.SetTitle('Messages')
        self.Centre()

        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex = wx.App()
    Example() # I moved None to super.__init__
    ex.MainLoop()
```